# Wireless router losing capability

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

My DLink D-320 router has worked fine for years. Recently, all the devices I own -- Windows, Ubuntu, Kindle -- are experiencing difficulty connecting.

They can't connect at a distance that used to be quite normal, and they sometimes report a connection when there is not one.

The router is in the same location as before.

What could  be causing this change in behavior?

Comment: Your neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ideas that spring to mind

1. overheating due to clogging of router vents with dust.
2. someone else is using the same channel which you can find out by running a scanner on a PC or android phone (inSSIDer for pc wifi anlyzer for android)
3. you have installed something that's using the same frequency range, a baby monitor or wireless channel changer for a tv are things I have found causing this issue

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. 

The router vents were  not dusty, though I tried to blow off any little dust there was. 

inSSIDER is a great tool -- thanks! I tried it and it does not show any conflict. 

Neighbors (but not super-close; just barely in range)  have two  routers  on channel 1 (2.4 GHz), and I switched  mine is at channel 11; that's all. 

I didn't install anything new. And the problem still exists.

Comment: I think it may be time to splash out on a new router then, if you wanted to really check you could take the router somewhere else and try it just to rule out the environment.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Any suggestions on how to choose a router that is good at connecting through concrete walls? 

It seems that they all have similar power. I considered upgrading to a router with 802.11n (though I'm not sure if that helps with range or wallpenetration), but in any case some of our devices are limited to 802.11g

Comment: I also have a DIR-300 router that I can  compare to the DIR-320. Unfortunately, our Ubuntu devices with Broadcom cards have other problems connecting to wifi, so it becomes hard to untangle causes.

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased a wireless AV sender unit to transmit sky to another room - Completely killed my wifi, and my neighbours. Have you purchased any devices like that?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good suggestion, but no new devices.

Comment: I can only suggest the d-link is recieving serious interference from a neighbour, or as many of my d-link routers have - gone wrong. Personally the best option I have found for a router is an asus rt-n16 running tomato, or an airport extreme. I have had little or no troubles with both of these routers. The apple will work straight out the box, but the rt-n16 will have to have it's firmware upgraded.